# Get type in referenced assembly by supplying class name as string?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly, gettype

These are similar questions: [How-to: Load a type from a referenced assembly at runtime using a string in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068131/how-to-load-a-type-from-a-referenced-assembly-at-runtime-using-a-string-in-silv), [GetType on a class in a referenced assembly fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233516/gettype-on-a-class-in-a-referenced-assembly-fails) but neither answer works.

I've got an MVC project that pulls data from a database that includes the plain types as strings. These types are in a referenced assembly, not in the MVC project.

So for example let's say my Referenced Assembly Name is `MyFramework` and the plain type name `Car`, the full type name could be `MyFramework.Cars.Car` or `MyFramework.Vehicles.Cars.Car` or some other variation. All I have are the referenced assembly name and plain class name as strings. How can I get the type regardless of the full type name?

Finally, could I write a function in the referenced assembly that calls GetType() and use that in the MvC project so I could forego including the assembly name? I want to remove knowing the assembly name so I thought I could write a Util IN the referenced assembly like:

```
namespace MyFramework //the referenced assembly
{
  public static class TypeUtil
  {
    public static Type GetFrameworkType(string typeName)
    {
        return Type.GetType(typeName);
    }
  }
}
```

And then in my MVC project I could call it without needing the assembly as a string name. Is that possible or will I always need the assembly name?

Comment: Why didn't the other answers work?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's because I just have the plain class name. Not the full type name. Those answers rely on knowing the full type.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Maybe the referenced assembly isn't loaded at the time. Also, I understand from your question that you do not have the full type name, only the class name. 
You should try something along this line then:

```
Type type = Assembly.Load("YourAssemblyName").GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == "ShortTypeName");
```

Hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: If I write a Util in that assembly but still only have the class name, how would it look? I'd like to remove the need for the assembly name by writing a `TypeUtil` class that can have a `GetTypeFromFramework(string typeName)` function. I thought if I call `GetType` in that assembly, I don't need to use the assembly at all, but it still returns null.

Comment: Please post a sample of what you're trying to do, so we could better understand your situation.

Comment: I edited the question. Your answer works when using it in my Util. I am just curious if I can remove the dependency on the assembly name as a string. I was under the impression that if I called GetType() in that assembly, I wouldn't need to supply the assembly name, but simply supplying `Type.GetType(class name)` kept returning null, even when this code was in the referenced assembly.

Comment: Well, this method would only work if you supply it with the namespace.

Comment: You don't have to have the assembly.. but atleast you need the full type name.

Comment: Okay, then I guess I'll stick to knowing the assembly instead. Because the full type name definitely won't be supplied.

Answer (score 11):

For the first question, you could do something like

```
Type t = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                .Where(a => a.FullName == "MyFramework")
                                .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Car");
```

I am not sure what you mean by the second question.