# How to get the class reference by a given string

Tags: c#, string, entity-framework, .net-assembly, class-reference

I'm working on some kind of scheduler, who gets the name of a class out of the DB and then executes a method of that class.

The problem is, that I can't get the reference to the class.

What I basically want:

```
    using MyNameSpace;
...
    Type myType = Type.GetType("MyNameSpace.MyClass");
    myInterface myObject = (myInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
    myObject.Run();
```

I know I need the assembly name so I tried something like this:

```
Type myType = typeof(object).Assembly.GetType("MyNameSpace.MyClass");
```

But the type is always null.

The wanted class lies in the same solution but in an other project. 
How can I get the referencee, so that I can execute the run() method?

thx

Comment: What do you think `typeof(object).Assembly` does? It'll return `mscorlib`, not your referenced assembly. `mscorlib` does not contain your types. Use an Assembly Qualified Name, see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512319/resolve-type-from-class-name-in-a-different-assembly).

Comment: The example in the "duplicate" is not working. It just works with System.String, but not with my own class:
Type myType = Type.GetType("CSTurbo.AppWeb.Lib.Jobs.UpdateMetadataJob, AssemblyName");

Comment: Then click one or two links further or try searching some more: [Type.GetType(“namespace.a.b.ClassName”) returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null), [Get type in referenced assembly by supplying class name as string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994057/get-type-in-referenced-assembly-by-supplying-class-name-as-string). Either the type is not in that assembly, or that assembly is not loaded. This question has been asked plenty of times before.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. But I'm trying and searching for three hours now...

Comment: That's no problem, did either of my links solve the problem now? If not, please [edit] your question to show your project structure (which project contains which assemblies and namespaces) and how exactly you're calling `Type.GetType()` and I'll be happy to reopen. Basically this issue is: `Type.GetType()` works for the current assembly (usually the code the assembly is in) and `mscorlib` only, unless you specify the assembly name (preferably fully qualified). When it's then still not finding your type, the assembly is not loaded or doesn't contain that type.

Answer (score 0):

try this
 Type myType = typeof(IMyInterface).Assembly.GetType("MyNameSpace.MyClass");