# Finding classes not working

Tags: c#

I try to get all classes implementing an interface with this method:

```
private static IEnumerable<Type> GetDriverClasses()
{
    var type = typeof(IDeviceDriver);
    var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass && !p.IsAbstract);
    return types;
}
```

This works as long as an instance of the class has been created. else it fails.
**How to get a class without having to create an instance first?**

*Additional info:*

DllSetup:
*Core.dll* holds the class with the above method
*Impl.dll* references Core and holds the class to find
*Test.dll* references both and calls the method

It seems connected to how assemblies are loaded as creating an instance of a dummy class in Impl.dll also makes the other class find-able.

Comment: Use [`AppDomain.Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36az8x58(v=vs.110).aspx) to force an assembly to be loaded into the app domain

Comment: It does not have anything to do with instances of classes but if the library (.dll) has been loaded yet into the application domain.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/11994178/34092 help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get type in referenced assembly by supplying class name as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994057/get-type-in-referenced-assembly-by-supplying-class-name-as-string)

Comment: Alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384592

Comment: Yes, its definitely the assembly not being loaded. So I will have to go the route of having a driver directory and loading all assemblies in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` will contain only the assemblies already loaded in the AppDomain - assemblies get loaded once a type of the assembly is used. You need to Load all assemblies yourself using `Assembly.LoadFrom(..)`.